# How to Create Multiple WordPress Sites Using Data from Spreadsheet

Tags: php, wordpress

I have been tasked with the following:

- create a WordPress site for each student (over 10000 students)
- load each site with a basic information about student (name, tutor group, email, etc. which I have in a spreadsheet)
- ensure each site has it's own subdomain in the format: studentname.example.com (I have already setup Wordpress MU to make this happen)

At present I am, manually creating a site a site, changing the theme to a responsive plugin, then manually copying in a skeleton of how the page should look, then filling the skeleton with data from the spreadsheet, before adding CSS to ensure it looks consistent on each one.

It takes a few moments for each record but since it is the same on each site, I am wondering if there is anyway to speed it up.

I am new to WordPress but if someone could briefly explain how this process (or at least some of it could be automated) then I will set to work to make that happen.

Thanks a lot guys and gals!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you need is [WP-CLI](http://wp-cli.org/) (WordPress Command Line Interface) where you can automate many WordPress actions.

You can even write your own commands:

https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/wiki/Commands-Cookbook